# conditional callback inside forEach and after forEach but doesnt seem to return as expected?

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
function(callback) {
  console.log(1, '*****');
  var array = ['hello'];
  array.forEach(element) {
    if (element === 'hello') {
      console.log(2, '*****');
      return callback(true); // doesn't end or return here. not sure why?
    }
  }
  console.log(3, '*****');
  return callback(false);
}

//current output
1 '*****'
2 '*****'
3 '*****'

//Desired output 
1 '*****'
2 '*****'
```

why does the control flow go all the way to end even though the if condition is satisfied? why it doesn't return the callback right there?

Comment: no and I am not sure why you ask such questions.

Comment: A callback is a function itself (or at least, would be, if you'd fixed your syntax errors - look at the `forEach` docs). `return` will only return from that function, not from the outer one.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement will not actually return to `function(callback)`, instead it returns value to the `forEach` function..

> From MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): Note: There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception. If you need such behaviour, the .forEach()
>   method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead. If you are testing
>   the array elements for a predicate and need a boolean return value,
>   you can use every() or some() instead.

Answer (score 0):

The return callback(true); ends the foreach function (because it's a function), thus, if you want to end the entire callback, you have to do something like this

```
function(callback) {
  console.log(1, '*****');
  var array = ['hello'];
  var endIt = false;
  array.forEach(element) {
    if (element === 'hello') {
      console.log(2, '*****');
      endIt = true;;
      return  // doesn't end or return here. not sure why?
    }
  }
  if( !endIt ) {
      console.log(3, '*****');
  }
  return callback(endIt);
}
```